# Terms in Nilakantha series in python

Tags: python

I know this is most likely an extremely simple piece of code but I just can't seem to figure out what in the world is wrong with it. I get 0 as an answer every time and if I try to just directly make pi = Pi it gives me a "float" error and says it is not callable.

```
def pi(n):
  result = 0;
  N= int(input("Input desired iterations: "))
  M = 1.0
  denom = 2.0
  Pi = 3.0
  for I in range (1, N+1):
      Pi += ((4.0/(denom*(denom+1)*(denom+2.0)))*M)
      denom += 2.0
      M *= -1.0
  return n == Pi

m = int(input("M: "))
actual_pi =3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062
for i in range(0, 50000) : 
  val = pi(i)
  if (val - actual_pi) <= (10 ** m):
      print(i)
      break
```

This should be the correct code I think but I can't get anything other than 0. [This is the question I'm trying to solve. It also has the answer I should be getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGlF3.png)

Edit: Just noticed that I did not include the correct number I should be getting in the picture. It's 24834.

Comment: Can you share the code in `nilakanthaWhile.py`? Note: `10**m` is very different from `10**-m`. It is unclear to me why you are asking for `N` the number of iterations.

Comment: The problem with the above is that `float` in python is not this accurate, try printing out `actual_pi` and it just shows `3.141592653589793` (the same as `math.pi`). Python does arbitrary precision decimals in the `decimal` module. Doing a couple of quick tests it shows me `24834` against `math.pi` (and `actual_pi`) and `29239` for an arbitrary precision `decimal` for `M=14`

Answer (score 0):

Your return expression, `n == Pi` is always `False`, which is arithmetically `0`.  Just return `Pi`.

EDIT2: The reason the output is still 0 is that Pi(0) - actualPi < 10**M for any non-negative M.

There are other problems, which can be avoid by putting the test for Pi inside the loop in the pi function, as shown below.

```
actual_pi =3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062
def pi(testexp=14):

    M = 1.0
    denom = 2.0
    Pi = 3.0
    for i in range(50000):
        delta = abs(Pi - actual_pi)
        if not i % 1000: print(i, delta)
        if delta <= (10 ** -14):
            return i - 1  # Last iteration did not change Pi
        else:
            Pi += ((4.0/(denom*(denom+1)*(denom+2.0)))*M)
            denom += 2.0
            M *= -1.0

print(pi())
# 24834
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to the problem is to create a generator for the "Nilakantha Series" and then just `enumerate()` the accumulated terms until you get to the error:

```
import itertools as it

Decimal = float
#from decimal import Decimal  # To use arbitrary precision decimal type

def nilakantha_series():
    yield Decimal(3)
    c = it.cycle([1, -1])
    for d in it.count(2, 2)
        yield Decimal(next(c)*4)/Decimal(d*(d+1)*(d+2))

def term_count(series, error, exact):
    for N, value in enumerate(it.accumulate(series)):
        if abs(value - exact) <= error:
            return N

In []:    
PI = Decimal('3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062')
M = 14
term_count(nilakantha_series(), 10**-M, PI)

Out[]:
24835
```

Note: if you uncomment out the import and remove `Decimal = float` then you get:

```
In []:
term_count(nilakantha_series(), 10**-M, PI)

Out[]:
29240
```